# Xcode - AVAudioPlayer redirect output to input AVAudioRecorder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder, avassetexportsession

I have an app that allows a user to record a guitar solo over a playing chord pattern track.  The problem is, the chord pattern track is a 12 second audio file set to loop in AVPlayer.  The user will be able to record up to 2 minutes over top of this.  But this means when I use AVAssetExportSession to combine the 2 tracks in the AVAsset into one .caf file I will only have the 12 second audio file and an 'n' minute guitar solo file.

Bearing in mind the user has the choice of using headphones or the speaker, Is it possible for me to capture the playing chord pattern track by redirecting it's AVPlayer output to the microphone (If the playing chord pattern is going through headphones, the mike won't pick it up)?

I could force the user to use the speaker during the recording, then the microphone would pick up the speaker's output (Containing the chord pattern file) but that doesn't allow me the ability to control the mix levels of each track.

Any opinions, or suggestions on how I should proceed would be very much appreciated.  Thanks in advance everyone!